# Error 'duplicate “message” entity' when running wsimport

Tags: java, maven, web-services, wsdl, wsimport

I've found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52123489/getting-error-duplicate-message-entity-when-running-wsimport) , but the answer is not valid for me.

#### Problem

I'm trying to create a Java Client using `wsimport` from a wsdl url , but I'm receiving an error that I can't understand neither what that means or how to fix.

### Code

I've tried both from terminal, with

```
 wsimport -keep -verbose https://www.infocar.org/QPServices/Services/ADSQPService.svc?WSDL
```

and with maven, running

```
 mvn generate-sources
```

In both cases i'm receiving the following error:

> [ERROR] duplicate "message" entity:
> "ISoapADSQPService_GetMarche_InputMessage"   row 1 of
> http://www.infocar.org/QPServices/Services/ADSQPService.svc?wsdl
>
> Exception in thread "main"
> com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.AbortException
> at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wsdl.framework.AbstractDocument.define(AbstractDocument.java:129)
> at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wsdl.document.Definitions.add(Definitions.java:81)
> at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.WSDLParser.parseDefinitionsNoImport(WSDLParser.java:278)
> at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.WSDLParser.processImports(WSDLParser.java:221)
> at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.WSDLParser.parseDefinitions(WSDLParser.java:210)
> at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.WSDLParser.buildWSDLDocument(WSDLParser.java:193)
> at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.WSDLParser.parse(WSDLParser.java:165)
> at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.buildModel(WSDLModeler.java:120)
> at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.buildWsdlModel(WsimportTool.java:429)
> at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.run(WsimportTool.java:190)
> at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.run(WsimportTool.java:168)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:159)
> at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.WsImport.main(WsImport.java:42)

#### Side notes

The url is public ( https://www.infocar.org/QPServices/Services/ADSQPService.svc?WSDL ), you can replicate the problem . I can't edit the target wsdl, because is not under my control.
In the maven's test, I've used this `pom.xml` configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>wsimport-from-jdk</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsimport</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <wsdlUrls>
            <wsdlUrl>
                https://www.infocar.org/QPServices/Services/ADSQPService.svc?WSDL
            </wsdlUrl>
        </wsdlUrls>
        <keep>true</keep>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```